# Raspberry Pi SD card appears as 3 SD cards

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, sd-card, cinnamon

I have purchased a raspberry pi 3 b+ kit from Amazon. No complaints, but recently I decided I would update NOOBS from 2.7 to 3.0.

When I connect the SD Card to my PC (Debian Stretch), it shows as if there’s 3 separate SD Cards. Being case sensitive, they’re called SETTINGS, System and Storage.

Why does this sd card show up as 3 separate card on my PC?

What I have tried:

- I deleted the contents of System, Storage and SETTINGS and replaced
  it with the files from NOOBS 3.0
- I google searched for why the sd card shows as 3
- I put my phone’s sd card into my PC and it showed as 1 sd card (but
  I’m not willing to switch cards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already run Debian on your PC, I would probably recommend you ignore NOOBS altogether, and just flash the whole Raspbian image to your SD card.

Then `touch boot/ssh` to start `sshd` and add a `wpa_supplicant` file to `boot` partition so your WiFi can connect.

When you then start your RasPi, just run `sudo raspi-config` and expand your root partition and all will be good.

Comment: Many Thanks! I also realized that the SD card showed up as 3 separate ones because the card was partitioned.